# How to scan a dynamodb table with a where condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting data in this get_item . how can I get this data in scan query where EventName='newevent'  and 'RekognitionId': {'S': match['Face']['FaceId']

```
 face = dynamodb.get_item(
                                    TableName='athlete_collection',
                                    Key={'RekognitionId': {'S': match['Face']['FaceId']}
                                        # ,'EventName': {'S' : 'celeb'}
                                         }
                                )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FilterExpression` as follows

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
expressionAttributeValues.put(":val", new AttributeValue().withN("0")); 

ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
    .withTableName("ProductCatalog")
    .withFilterExpression("Price < :val")
    .withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues);


ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);
for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : result.getItems()) {
    printItem(item);
}
```

For more details refer [Filter Expressions for Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.FilterExpression)